# Does the US republican party have a demographics problem?

Tags: united-states, voting, republican-party, demographics

I've read in various articles that, among voters for the U.S. Republican Party, middle-aged white men are (strongly) over-represented, whereas among voters for the U.S. Democratic Party, voters from other groups (African-Americans, Hispanics, women, young people) are over-represented. Then I have read the subsequent analysis that this poses a problem for the U.S. Republican Party, because the demographics where they are strong is shrinking.

A [quick Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=republican+party+demographics) turns up many articles discussing the issue.

Is this true? Do people vote according to their demographics (*this is a candidate I can relate to, he talks about my kind of people*), or is this subject to quite rapid changes so that the picture between subsequent elections might change radically?

Comment: Asking if people vote according to their demographics would certainly make for an interesting roundtable discussion. But questions that elicit extended debates and on-going discussion can't really be properly answered in *this* format. Some questions actually *need* that type of discussion; there's nothing wrong with that. But they are simply better suited to a threaded discussion forum. Of course, they are also welcome in our [chat rooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com/), as it *is* a topic of interest to the folks here. It's just not a good fit for a Stack Exchange-style Q&A.

Comment: @Zero: consider editing the question to reflect that answer. If you honestly believe the question is fine as it stands, raise a discussion on [meta] - but think a bit about the other sorts of answers that would be technically valid here first...

Comment: And the reasonable sector of Americans is constantly shrinking. According to 2000 U.S. census, only 8.7% Americans are English, only 5.6% are Italian. Nowadays, you don't even see Frenchman in Paris. I wonder where they went.

Comment: Clinton is definitely not English. Knock-offs like this spell disaster for America.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer this question, there are two questions that need to be answered:  1) Are demographics a consist/stable indicator of party affiliation? 2) Are the demographics of the electorate that are growing more likely to be aligned with the Democratic party?

To answer the first question, it is not difficult to find plenty of polling that has shown over the course of entire generations demographics do tend to stick with a particular political party.  The chart below from the Pew Research Center is just one such example that shows remarkable stability across most demographic groups despite the large and controversial changes the country was undergoing throughout the two elections represented below.

[image: Demographic Chart]

From this graph from the United States Census Bureau, we can take the information from above about party affiliation and determine if the groups that are growing represent those that more often favor the Democratic party:

[image: Census]

So with an increase projection from 17% to 31% of the population, right off the bat we can see that the roughly 20% point lead for Democrats with Hispanics is going to be a potential problem for them over the long term.  Similarly, the Republican electoral advantage with White voters is likely to be impacted by the decrease projected for that population from 78% of the country to 69%.

Additionally, since the national popular vote does not elect presidents in the United States, it is worth looking at the trend specifically for large Electoral College states.  The biggest two contributors of electoral college votes are California and Texas.  The real concern for the Republican party is these are also the two states with the largest Hispanic population growth.  The problem is only exacerbated in these states.  California doesn't actually pose too much of a concern for the modern Republican party, however, as they have not been competitive there in many years in state wide elections.  Texas, however, is a solidly Republican state and a shift of power in this state would be even more detrimental to their national chances than these trends in other states.

The real **potential for change** in this equation is the party itself as it is much more nimble than the population.  During the 19th century for example, it was the Republican party led by President Lincoln that were the socially liberal caucus and civil rights legislation was passed over the loud objections of the Democratic party.  If the Republican party adopts a similar shift toward policies that are favored by the Hispanic population this balance could shift dramatically.

**That action/inaction will really underline how much of a problem demographics become for the party long term.**

Comment: For #1, there are also probably plenty of examples of demographics which have had major shifts in party affiliation. Mormons for example. Mormons use to affiliate primarily with the Democratic party until the 50's and 60's. I'm willing to bet there are other examples too.

Comment: @mikeazo - Absolutely!  But I think you will find, more often than not, that the catalyst was a shift in the party platform, rather than the underlying voting habits of that bloc of the electorate.  Thus my caveat at the end.

Comment: I'm not sure a chart of two recent elections proves the "over the course of entire generations" claim.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple issues at play here

- Democrats Are more in-favor of Social Justice and protecting or giving additional advantages to minorities, and if you are a minority, such policies benefit you, and it makes all the sense in the world to support it.
- Democrats are also more in-favor or providing for the poor(which also is disproportionally a minority group), and if you are poor, democrat policies benefit you.
- Democrats are also less aggressive toward immigration, and apparently being aggressive toward immigration is frowned upon by immigrants.

Also, the term `Demographics` can mean a lot of things.  It can be based on age, or even physical size, education, occupation, the kinds of hobbies you have, or even your own voting habits.

In essence any set of people distinguished based on a criteria is a demographic.

It's only natural that one parties' policies benefit specific demographics over others.

Comment: Yet a large group of poor, middle-aged white men would benefit from democrat policies as well, yet [vote Republican for moral reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What%27s_the_Matter_with_Kansas%3F). And many Hispanics have conservative social values, yet don't vote Republican. So I think it's more complicated than "people vote in their own interest".

Comment: @gerrit large groups of poor/middle-class/rich middle-aged white men vote democratic too, and lots of minorities and women vote republican.  Demographics doesn't determine 100% of how people vote, it only indicates certain trends

Comment: @gerrit and religions are also demographics

Comment: If I am an immigrant in some southern states I can still, thanks to Republican measures, be stopped and questioned without cause, even if I am 100% legal. That's one of the things meant by 'aggressive towards immigrants'.